# DSE SOLR OOMing

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We have had a 3 node DSE SOLR cluster running and recently added a new core.  After about a week of running fine, all of the SOLR nodes are now OOMing.  The fill up both the JVM Heap (set at 8GB) and the system memory.  Then are also constantly flushing the memtables to disk.

The cluster is DSE 3.2.5 with RF=3

here is the solrconfig from the new core:

http://pastie.org/8973780

Answer (score 0):

How big is your Solr index relative to the amount of system memory available for the OS to cache file system pages. Basically, your Solr index needs to fit in the OS file system cache (the amount of system memory available after DSE is started but has not yet processed any significant amount of data.)

Also, how many Solr documents (Cassandra rows) and how many fields (Cassandra columns) are populated on each node? There is no hard limit, but 40 to 100 million is a good guideline as an upper limit - per node.

And, how much system memory and how much JVM heap is available if you restart DSE, but before you start putting load on the server?

Comment: How do I check the SOLR index size?  There are 3 cores, 2 of which have about 35 million documents and about 13 fields, the other has about 65 million documents and 14 fields. I'm not sure how to test the server without load as I can not stop it from taking writes.

Comment: Is 40-100m an upper limit on node size regardless of compute power and memory on the machine? iow. Is using a more powerful machine not going to make a difference? And if 40-100m is the cap, does that mean it makes sense from a DSE Solr/C* performance perspective to make a lot of less powerful machines with more disk space?

Comment: None of those are hard limits - just ballpark guidelines before you need to be a lot more careful. Sometimes bigger and faster machines help, but a lot of the time more smaller machines help more since Solr can be so compute and I/O intensive (if index doesn't fit in memory.)

Comment: To get the Solr index size, look in the cassandra/solr directory. It's just the sum of all the subdirectories for Solr on a node.

Comment: The solr index size (as calculated from cassandra/data/solr.data/) is 43G

Answer (score 0):

For RF=N, where N is the total number of nodes in the cluster or at least the search data center, all of the data will be stored on all nodes, which is okay for smaller datasets, but not okay for larger datasets.

For RF=n, this means that each node will have X/N*n rows or documents, where X is the total number of rows or documents all column families in the data center. X/N*n is the number that you should try to keep below 100 million. That's not a hard limit - some datasets and hardware might be able to handle substantially more, and some datasets and hardware might not even be able to hold that much. You'll have to discover the number that works best for your own app, but the 40 million to 100 million range is a good start.

In short, the safest estimate is for X/N*n to be kept under 40 million for Solr nodes. 100 may be fine for some data sets and beefier hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As far as tuning, one common source of using lots of heap is heavy use of Solr facets and filter queries.

One technique is to use "DocValues" fields for facets since DocValues can be stored off-heap.

Filter queries can be marked as cache=false to save heap memory.

Also, the various Solr caches can be reduced in size or even set to zero. That's in solrconfig.xml.